# Change content of ContentControl WPF using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a project using MVVM with WPF and I'm in a difficult spot.

When I create a `Button` and a `ContentControl` in a window where the button changes the content of the `ContentControl`, it works fine.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <me:UserControl1ViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"
            Name="button1"
            Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=ClickCommand}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=View, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
</Grid>
```

But when I create a UserControl with a button and the button changes the content of the ContentControl does not work.
Why?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <me:UserControl1ViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <v:UserControl1 />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=View, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl that is calling the change of the contents of the ContentControl

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <me:UserControl1ViewModel x:Key="viewModelA" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"
            Name="button1"
            Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelA}, Path=ClickCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does you ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is in your second example you are bound to two different view models.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- View Model Instance #0 -->
    <me:UserControl1ViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- View Model Instance #1 -->
    <me:UserControl1ViewModel x:Key="viewModelA" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Basically, your UserControl and Window are not sharing the same view model instance, thus updates are not propagated. You'll need to get the same instance to your user control.

How about:

```
<!-- Window -->
<v:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" />

<!-- UserControl1 -->
<Button Content="Button"
        Name="button1"
        Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand}" />
```