# WPF MVVM how to set initial value of contentcontrol

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have implemented something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074072/change-content-of-contentcontrol-wpf-using-mvvm) in my application. In my xaml I have this:

```
Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type local:View1ViewModel}">
        <local:View1/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type local:View2ViewModel}">
        <local:View2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
```

This works and I can change between the views by setting the "CurrentView" property in the VM. But I'm wondering how to set a initial value (before user interacts)? Currently I have this in my VM:

```
CurrentView = new View1();
```

But is that following MVVM? It seems wrong since I'm referencing / instantiating a View from my ViewModel. It would be nicer if this could be declared in the xaml instead. Is that possible?

Comment: That line of code is in your window viewmodel?  I would say it is usual to have CurrentView = new View1ViewModel();  Then datatemplate that into View1.

Comment: Hopefully CurrentView does not hold View1 or View2 references. The whole data templating would be useless then. It should instead hold references to View1ViewModel or View2ViewModel objects.

Comment: I was following http://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/switching-between-wpf-xaml-views-using-mvvm-datatemplate/. But I see your points.

Comment: The author of that "recipe" must be a different Andy. Anyway, you should forget about it. Not everything on the internet is useful.

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvote unless my question was unclear. I'm in a MVVM learning phase here so...anyways would it be correct implementation if the "CurrentView" property was ViewModel references?

Comment: Yes, that will be correct.

Comment: @Andy is right and should put that in an answer with code example. CurrentView should be a property on your Window's DataContext, and seeing as you're using DataType on your templates correctly (DataType equals one of your view models), instances of these view models (e.g., View1ViewModel) should be placed in CurrentView. WPF takes care of the rest.

Comment: That Andy is  a different Andy. I like to think I'd do a better job if I took the time to write such an article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, CurrentView should really be CurrentViewModel if you want to do viewmodel first. Otherwise those templates are a bit pointless.
Here's something I put together a while back.
MainWindow:

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}">
        <local:UserUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Login Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}"
                />
        <Button Content="User Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}"
                />
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                    />
</Grid>
```

Notice that I have one command which takes a Type as a parameter.
There are templates for those two types which give you the views.
Oh.... and I called my property CurrentViewModel. Because it's going to present an instance of one of those viewmodels to the content of my contentcontrol.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object currentViewModel;

    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set { currentViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private RelayCommand<Type> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Type> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return navigateCommand
              ?? (navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(
                vmType =>
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
                }));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the property to null first guarantees you don't retain any state in a view. I take the type which is passed in from the command and create an instance of that viewmodel. It's then templated out by the appropriate datatemplate.  This is a particularly simple illustrative sample only and one obvious improvement would be to retain state of each viewmodel using a dictionary keyed on type. So you instantiate any given viewmodel type just the once in a session.

That is viewmodel first.

Some people prefer view first. And of course if you wanted a new window each time then maybe that's the direction you want to head in.  View first is arguably a view responsibility and you could handle instantiating a new view in the view itself. If you wanted.  That could be done using a routed event and parameter.

Which could look like:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 Button.Click="Button_Click"
                  >
            <Button Content="Home" Tag="{x:Type local:HomeView}"/>
            <Button Content="Departments" Tag="{x:Type local:DepartmentView}"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ContentControl Name="NavigationParent"
                        Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

This version retains state of each view. The view would instantiate it's own viewmodel in this pattern.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Navigate(typeof(HomeView));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
        Navigate(btn.Tag as Type);
    }

    private void Navigate (Type viewType)
    {
        UserControl uc;
        if (Views.ContainsKey(viewType))
        {
            uc = Views[viewType];
        }
        else
        {
            uc = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
            Views[viewType] = uc;
        }
        NavigationParent.Content = uc;
    }
    private Dictionary<Type, UserControl> Views = new Dictionary<Type, UserControl>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **ActivateItem** method from **Conductor** class,

First let **ShellViewModel** the inherit from **Conductor**

```
public class ShellViewModel :Conductor<object>
```

then in the constracter

```
public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ActivateItem(new HomePageChildViewModel());
        }
```

Where the **HomePageChildViewModel** is what you want to display by defult.