# Change page of contentcontrol in a page

Tags: c#, contentcontrol

I have `ContentControl` and two UserControls (u1.xaml and u2.xaml)

In MainWindow, I change content of `ContentControl` using `ContentControl.Content = new u1();`

How can I change content of `ContentControl` to `u2` using a button inside `u1`?

I can't access ContentControl from u1, and if it's not possible, how should I do it?

MainWindow.xaml

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.cc.Content = new uc1();
        }
    }
```

uc1.xaml

```
public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Can't access it...//this.cc.Content = new uc2();
        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to hardwire two content-controls. The page should handle an event of the first control, then the page can change it's `Content` in the event-handler.

Comment: Rather than setting `Content` directly consider using datatemplates.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content of the ContentControl using [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074072/change-content-of-contentcontrol-wpf-using-mvvm) and take a look at [event aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to have it set from the other Usercontrol